# Javascript toSource() "steals" my comment?

Tags: javascript, firefox, comments

I use Firefox 49.0.1/Macosx. I got only the 1. comment in console.log, but where is my 2. comment?

```js
var a = {
  b: function() {
      var c = 'c'; // comment1
    } // comment2
};

console.log(a.toSource());
```

console.log:

```
({b:(function () {
      var c = 'c'; // comment1
    })})
```